# Possible to detect installed browser languages?

Tags: localization, internationalization

In a current website I am delegating the production of error messages to the HTML5 Validation API. That is, if the form is invalid, I just present the messages produced by `Element.validationMessage`. This works great! The only thing is that this is a Norwegian website, for a Norwegian speaking audience, and some users (developers, usually) have installed American Windows versions that have no Norwegian language packs. Thus the messages they see are in English, even though their preferred language is Norwegian.

[image: actual error message]

Output from console

[image: output from US IE11]

So what I would like is to present some generic validation error message *in Norwegian* if the user runs a browser where the preferred language is Norwegian, but the language support is missing.

Is it at all possible to do this? I would think not.

edit: Server based solutions using Headers are accepted! This need not be a browser-only thing.

Comment: There is no correlation between the languages specified as preferred languages (for content), and the browser UI. What you get send via the `Accept-Language` request header, is only the former. And I don’t think common browsers send info about their UI language any other way.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. The only reasonable heuristic I can think of is to compare `navigator.language` (preferred language) to `navigator.systemLanguage` or `navigator.browserLanguage`, to check if preferred language is different from the operating system language. If the preferred language is "nb-NO" and the operating system is something else, then the user will probably get error messages in English.